# Representation for a method applied on a class in Python

Tags: python, oop

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class Human(object):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.last_name
```

And I know I can define a `__repr__` method for it:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Human being, named " + str(self.name) + " " + str (self.last_name)
```

However, what if I want to define a  separate representation for a `lastname` method, too? I.e., if this is a sample:

```
>>> me = Human("Jane", "Doe")
>>> me
Human being, named Jane Doe
>>> me.get_last_name()
'Doe'
```

…then I want the last output be not only the string `'Doe'` itself but something like `Human being's last name is Doe` – how can it be done? How to define a `__repr__` (or a `__str__`) method for a method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a special attribute for a function or another attribute. In this case since you have `self.last_name` in your `__init__` function, instead of returning it back in `get_last_name()` you can apply expected changes on `last_name` here and return the expected format.

```
class Human(object):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def get_last_name(self):
        # return expected format
```

And you can directly access `last_name` if you want to see the raw data.

```
me = Human("Jane", "Doe")
print(me.last_name)
```

Comment: I.e., in order to have both `'Doe'` and `Human being's last name is Doe`, I have to define two different methods, something like `get_last_name()` and `get_last_name_gorgeously()`? No other way around?

Comment: @AS Sorry I cant got you. When you want separate representations you need to use separate callers. Other wise the result would be same. Or maybe based on different input you produce separate output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want **readable** representation override `__str__` method. For obtain **unambiguous** output override `__repr__`

Comment: Yeah, got that [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python), thanks!